# Apache Beam PubSubToBigQuery.java duplicate removal?

Tags: duplicates, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using PubSubToBigQuery.java code without any changes. Would someone please show me how to remove duplicate records during this process?

I know the trick is to create Window and use GroupBy but really not know how to write it.

Thanks

Comment: Is this code that you are talking about? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java

Comment: yes. That's the code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to filter duplicate on successful parsed events. You will need to add some code after [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java#L212):

```
transformOut
    .get(TRANSFORM_OUT)
    .apply("keyed", WithKeys.of(/* choose your key from table row to identify duplicates */))
    .apply(GroupByKey.create())
    .apply("dedup", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>, TableRow>() {
      public void ProcessElement(ProcessContext context) {
        // only output one element from list to dedup.
        context.output(context.element().getValue().iterator().next());
      }
    }
    ))
    .apply(Window.configure().triggering(/* choose your trigger */)
    .apply(
        "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
        BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
            .withoutValidation()
            .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
            .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .to(options.getOutputTableSpec()));
```

BeamSQL actual tries to support your use case (check [PubsubToBigqueryIT.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/PubsubToBigqueryIT.java)). BeamSQL allows you create table on pubsub topic and bigquery table. Read from pubsub, convert pubsub messages and write to BQ table are handled by BeamSQL already. SQL can be applied to data that read from pubsub. However, BeamSQL might miss some features (for example, ANY_VALUE aggregation function if you want use group by to dedup in SQL) to finish your task.